# E-Tape Liquid Level Sensor w/ Raspberry Pi Zero W

Tags: pi-3

I am looking for help in determining how to use a [Milone E-Tape](https://milonetech.com/products/standard-etape-assembly) liquid level sensor with a raspberry pi zero w.

The datasheet for the device is [here](http://www.original.milonetech.com/uploads/Standard_eTape_Datasheet.pdf).

It appears a voltage divider circuit will be needed, but how would this work with a Raspberry Pi Zero W?  Also, the documentation talks about using the reference resister for temperature compensation - how would this be done?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You will need an ADC as the Pis have no analogue inputs.  You will probably be better off asking this question on another site as the Pi will be irrelevant to most of the solution.

Comment: Thank you.  I am new to the Pis and only have experience with the Arduino.  For this particular application the PI is a must for other reasons.  As such it would be very helpful to get advice on the hookup of the Pi to something like a MCP3008 and then to the E-Tape sensor.

Answer (score -1):

I use this exact sensor but I use it with an Arduino clone as opposed to the Pi itself but the code that I use might help. You can see additional information here:

https://github.com/rjsears/Pool_Fill_Control

and even more info here:

https://www.hackster.io/user3424878278/pool-fill-control-119ab7